# Making websites use proxies?

Tags: web-application, network

Recently, I've been thinking about trying to make a website have a hidden ip, and make it so that it is extremely hard to find the real ip. I want to have it use proxies so that you can connect to the proxy server to connect to the real site. That way, it would never get blocked as I could keep adding new proxies for it to use. I would put cloudfare on the proxy servers for additional protection. Does anyone know where I could get a good guide/explanation of how to do this?

Comment: You're essentially talking about a service Cloudflare do already: they provide the exposed IP addresses, and you have a box which is locked down to only respond to requests from the Cloudflare servers. There is still a potential for DoS attacks (there aren't that many IPv4 addresses - can scan them all in 45 mins!) but if you're not responding to anything other than Cloudflare, it should be hard to identify which of the unresponsive boxes is yours, without some kind of leak elsewhere.

Comment: `Does anyone know where I could get a good guide/explanation of how to do this?` - IMO this is the same thing as asking for a product recommendation. Google is the answer to that question. I am going to flag this as I don't deem it to be a high-quality question and is on edge with being a product recommendation. To add to this; the term "good guide" is merely an opinion. We could *all* link you a "good guide" but it's our perception of good, you might find it useless.

Comment: If you looking for service availability option,  you should ask the question in servefault  startexchange.  Cloudflare is already cloud base CDN, there is no reason to add another proxy to hide the IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Making websites use proxies?

The question is the wrong way. A web server does not **use** a proxy. A web server is just listening for incoming connections. Instead the client which connects to the server might use knowingly or transparently use a proxy which then forwards the original clients traffic to the server and the response from the server back to the client.

Thus the question is not how to make your website use a proxy but how to make the client use a proxy to connect to the website. This can be done by giving the proxy the domain name your site should have so that the client will actually connect to the proxy when trying to connect to your site. The proxy then of course needs to know where to forward the traffic too, i.e. it needs to know the hidden name of the site or its IP address or have a VPN connection or similar to the hidden site. And your hidden site better only accepts connections from the proxy and from nowhere else.

To achieve such a setup you either need to have control over the proxies so that they will respond to the domain name of your site and know where to forward the traffic too. Or you hand over management of the relevant parts of the domain to the owners of the proxy, like done in case of CDN like Cloudflare.  And of course your hidden IP address is known on the proxy and might be available to law enforcement depending on where your proxy is and what law can be applied there.

> That way, it would never get blocked as I could keep adding new proxies for it to use.

This is true only if the blocking is based on IP address. Given that it is common to have multiple domains on the same IP address today this kind of blocking can easily result in blocking innocent domains too (i.e. overblocking) and that's why modern ways to block web sites instead rely on hijacking the DNS lookup for the sites and return that the domain does not exist or the IP address of a blocking site instead. Thus you would not only use a different proxy all the time but also change your domain name and somehow propagate the new domain name to all which like to visit your site.

Or your could rely on a different infrastructure for mapping names to IP addresses, like [Dot-Bit (namecoin)](https://bit.namecoin.org/). Only the use of these alternative systems requires then additional setup at each client in the form of browser extensions or local DNS servers which are able to resolve these special domains.

Of course, if you have full control over the clients (for example in case you are implementing C2 communication inside your own malware) then you are not bound by the traditional methods of finding the correct proxy. But this is hopefully not your use case.

Comment: `web server does not use a proxy` nitpicking, but a reverse proxy is a form of proxy that can be used with a web server

Comment: @CaffeineAddiction: A reverse proxy is essentially what I describe: DNS is configured so that the client connects to the reverse proxy and not the hidden server and the proxy is configured to forward the traffic to the hidden server. Still, the configuration done for this is not at the website (i.e. the hidden server) but at the reverse proxy and DNS which means that the website is not changed to use a proxy (i.e. not *"Making websites use proxy"*) but the setup around the website is changed to make the client use the proxy (instead *Making client use proxy*)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a freely accessible website, then you can't hide the IP and hostname of your frontend. And the bans will relate to them.

You can make a private service on the tor network, but then the site will be visible only for the tor users.

The hosting company, where your frontend works, will know a lot more about your backend as you would think. They are not idiot and if somebody does this, it means an extra risk for them. You can reduce this if also the communication between your frontend and backend is going on a private channel, for example on the tor network, or on VPNs.

Comment: `You can't hide the IP and hostname of your frontend` unless you are hosting a Tor only website

Comment: @CaffeineAddiction I think the question relates specifically for public websites (or, at least sites with a public frontend), although the OP didn't mention it in the question. So I improved the post to make it clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Recently, I've been thinking about trying to make a website have a hidden ip, and make it so that it is extremely hard to find the real ip. I want to have it use proxies so that you can connect to the proxy server to connect to the real site

That is what *reverse proxies* are made for, and it is the common way to install application servers in datacenters: the server is not exposed to internet, only the reverse proxy is.

> That way, it would never get blocked as I could keep adding new proxies for it to use.

? For what I know you must ensure that:

- the reverse proxies can accept the number of connections that you want your server to support
- **and** the server accept that number of connections

> I would put cloudfare on the proxy servers for additional protection.

Why not...

> Does anyone know where I could get a good guide/explanation of how to do this?

Just google for *reverse proxy* - BTW Apache HTTPD and nginx are known to be good at reverse proxying, at have correct documentation for how to do that.